# Trekstor laptop bluetooth adapter not working in Kubuntu 21.04

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, bluetooth

I'm using Kubuntu 21.04 on a Trekstor SurfBook W2 laptop and the bluetooth is not working. I think the adapter is not even detected correctly. Not 100% sure but it might be a Broadcom Wifi/Bluetooth adapter. The wifi works fine.

```
uname -mr; lsb_release -d; 
5.11.0-25-generic x86_64
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
```

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 22)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 22)
00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 22)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 22)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 22)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 22)
```

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1018:1006  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:5608 Alcor Micro Corp. USB 2.0 Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

```
hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
        UP RUNNING 
        RX bytes:2200 acl:0 sco:0 events:116 errors:0
        TX bytes:5730 acl:0 sco:0 commands:115 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
        Name: 'alouestdeden-SurfBook-W2'
        Class: 0x3c010c
        Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio
        Device Class: Computer, Laptop
        HCI Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Revision: 0x0
        LMP Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Subversion: 0x2122
        Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```

```
sudo dmesg | grep Blue
[    8.610985] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    8.611077] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.611088] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.611094] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.611106] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.825846] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    8.825862] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    8.825866] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    8.825929] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    8.825934] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    8.826008] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    8.859750] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    8.859985] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    8.860013] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    8.860018] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    8.860042] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    9.115179] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: failed to write clock (-56)
[    9.115204] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to set baudrate
[    9.231108] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 94
[    9.235191] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x2e
[    9.259648] Bluetooth: hci0: 4343A0
[    9.259667] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4343A0 (001.001.034) build 0000
[    9.259835] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[    9.259845] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM4343A0.hcd'
[    9.259850] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM.hcd'
[   12.300439] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   12.300452] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   12.300465] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   17.321873] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   17.321903] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   17.321924] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

```
dpkg -l | grep blue
ii  bluedevil                                     4:5.22.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu21.04~ppa1                                   amd64        KDE Bluetooth stack
ii  bluetooth                                     5.56-0ubuntu4.2                                                      all          Bluetooth support
ii  bluez                                         5.56-0ubuntu4.2                                                      amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-cups                                    5.56-0ubuntu4.2                                                      amd64        Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
ii  bluez-obexd                                   5.56-0ubuntu4.2                                                      amd64        bluez obex daemon
ii  bluez-tools                                   2.0~20170911.0.7cb788c-4                                             amd64        Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux
ii  libbluetooth3:amd64                           5.56-0ubuntu4.2                                                      amd64        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  libkf5bluezqt-data                            5.84.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu21.04~ppa1                                     all          data files for bluez-qt
ii  libkf5bluezqt6:amd64                          5.84.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu21.04~ppa1                                     amd64        Qt wrapper for bluez
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                   1:14.2-1ubuntu1.1                                                    amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  qml-module-org-kde-bluezqt:amd64              5.84.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu21.04~ppa1                                     amd64        QML wrapper for bluez
```

I've upgraded bluez package to latest (latest i could without compiling with GIT because of dependencies problems).
I'll try to extract the probable Broadcom's firmware from Windows's driver like a answer on a bug report says, but not sure i've got the skills to do it.

So any help is more than welcome :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't put [SOLVED] in the question title. Accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark next to your answer and turn it green. This will mark your question as solved, and help others.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution !

After an internet search i've found the missing firmware named BCM4343A0.hcd (i had to rename it correctly) then i've copied it in folder **/usr/lib/frimware/brcm**.
After a reboot the Bluetooth was working fine.

The file was shown missing by **sudo dmesg | grep Blue**

The firmware was downloaded here [Frirmware for Broadcom BCM4343A0](https://gitlab.com/TeeFirefly/FireNow-Marshmallow/blob/061bdfd4bdd7cce2fe55e1013f3d3f23de7603ca/vendor/rockchip/common/bluetooth/lib/firmware/4343A0.hcd)

More info here [missing /usr/lib/firmware/brcm/BCM4343A0.hcd](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1622367)

Thx anyway :D

Comment: I am happy that you have found a solution to your question and decided to answer your own question. A link only answer is not considered sufficient in this site. Links change and break all the time. Please edit your question and add the essential steps one would need to follow to use your solution.

Comment: Hi,Ok 'll do so

Comment: The provided link seems to stopped working. I used this file though and it worked I think: https://github.com/LibreELEC/brcmfmac_sdio-firmware/blob/master/BCM4343A0.hcd . Thank You anyway.
By the way - You can mark this answer as a solution I believe.